# How to maintain a movieclip's color between frames?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colors, frames, movieclip

My app has 2 frames; in frame 1 there are 5 MC and on a `DOUBLE_CLICK` event the target's color change and go to the next frame 2.
In frame 2 I have a button to return to frame 1.

How can i maintain the MC color when I return to frame 1?

```
public class test extends MovieClip
{
    public function test()
    {
        var myMCTable:Array = [myMC1, myMC2, myMC3, myMC4, myMC5];
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < myMCTable.length; i++)
        {
            myMCTable[i].doubleClickEnabled = true;
            myMCTable[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, changeColor);
        }
    }

    private function changeColor(e:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        var newColorTransform:ColorTransform = (e.target).transform.colorTransform;
        newColorTransform.color = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
        (e.target).transform.colorTransform = newColorTransform;
        nextFrame();
        goBack_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
    }

    private function goBack(e:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        prevFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer to your other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248404/movieclip-color-is-not-working-properly/8248661

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to have three frames, create your MCs on frame 1 and switch between frame 2 and 3.

You could also store the color information in an object.

```
_color[e.target.id] = newColorTransform.color;
```

And then retrieve it and apply it. But there again you will need to have the initialization of your data object on a previous, third frame. If you don't it will be reinitialized and you will lose your colors.

Comment: But i want to work only with 2 frames... can you be more specific please?

Comment: Every time you read the first frame, every variable and every clip created in this frame will be reinitialized. You should have a first keyframe in which stuff are declared and clips created, and then only navigate through other frames.

Comment: Well, my animation consists of 2 frames, in frame1, i have declared the variables and created the clips, and frame2 which contains a button to return to frame1. See the pics http://s257.photobucket.com/albums/hh232/fradiavolo912/?action=view&current=frame2a.jpg and http://s257.photobucket.com/albums/hh232/fradiavolo912/?action=view&current=frame1a.jpg. What you are saying is to create a variable (eg _color) to hold the color information? PS: in both frames i have the "stop()" function.

Comment: Yes you could use a variable but you must not declare it on the frame you are coming back to. If you do so the variable will be overwritten and you will lose the data.

Comment: This is totally out of topic but you REALLY shouldn't leave your ID card scan on your public photobucket gallery.

Comment: I am using document class, not frame scripts so i am confused where to declare it

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that, then it's ok, you can declare it in your class.

Comment: If you look above you will see the code and i already declared a variable (var newColorTransform) to hold the color value.

Comment: your variable shouldn't be local, you have to declare it outside of the function.

Comment: I have declared var newColorTransform:ColorTransform; outside the function, but it doesnt work only if i delete "nextFrame();
" in "changeColor" function

Comment: I think the problem is the nextFrame(), but i do not know why.

Comment: can you please look at the following pictures and tell me what i do wrong: http://www.picz.ro/show-image.php?id=ec122060763b0fd744d2499882d4ae1f and http://www.picz.ro/show-image.php?id=00e207dfad35e7e414ed3236a1f79448

Answer (score 0):

If you make a class for the movieclips (you have 5 I believe) that they all share. Create a class property called myColor, then update each individual movieclip object's "myColor" property whenever it is double-clicked and the color changes, you can make the "goBack()" method re-apply each movieclip's color from its own property.

Does this make sense?