# Movieclip color is not working properly?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colors, frames, movieclip

I have 2 frames and in frame 1 the target MC color is being changed to RED. After that i go to frame 2. If i came back to frame 1 the MC doesn't retain the RED color. What i do wrong. Please see the pictures. 
http://www.picz.ro/index.php?id=ec122060763b0fd744d2499882d4ae1f and http://www.picz.ro/index.php?id=00e207dfad35e7e414ed3236a1f79448

Comment: You should post some of your code. You also can embed those pictures in the post to make them easier to access. (There is a little picture icon in the tools above the text area.)

Comment: you should just not use frames all together. You really only need one frame. The rest can be done in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eliminating frames, you can do it with code like this:

```
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var newColorTransform:ColorTransform;
var myMCTable:Array = [myMC1,myMC2,myMC3,myMC4,myMC5];

for (var i:int = 0; i < myMCTable.length; i++)
{
    myMCTable[i].doubleClickEnabled = true;
    myMCTable[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, changeColor);
}

function changeColor(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    newColorTransform = (e.target).transform.colorTransform;
    newColorTransform.color = 0xFF0000;
    (e.target).transform.colorTransform = newColorTransform;
}
prevNextBtn.txt.mouseEnabled = false;
prevNextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevNext);

function prevNext(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var i:int;
    if (e.target.txt.text == "next")
    {
        e.target.txt.text = "prev";
        for (i = 0; i < myMCTable.length; i++)
        {
            myMCTable[i].visible = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.target.txt.text = "next";
        for (i = 0; i < myMCTable.length; i++)
        {
            myMCTable[i].visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

all that you need to change besides the code, is now you have just one button with a text field in it called "txt" and the label just changes

Comment: The line "prevNextBtn.txt.mouseEnabled = false;
" yields this error: Access of possibly undefined property txt through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.

Comment: Never mind my last comment. I have successfully done it. Thanks